# Closing sequence of inserts (that return autoinc id) as a single DBIOAction

Tags: slick

**TL;DR:** I want to create a pure function that will return a sequence of insert operations closed inside a single DBIOAction object (e.g def foo(): DBIOAction). This is trivial when IDs are NOT auto-incremented, it gets difficult for me when ID's ARE auto-incremented by DB).

I've been using Slick for more then a week now and what I really like about it is ability to close sequence of operations as a DBIOAction, that can be returned by my function and later can be applied to DB as a side effect.

That worked all fine when I was inserting data to a single table. But how should I deal with situation when an ID of one inserted row must be used in a second row that I'm inserting (like any 1-many relation), given the fact that IDs are auto-incremented?

Imagine we have a `CATEGORIES table` with columns: `id, name, parent_id`, where `parent_id` is either NULL or points to other row within the table.

If the IDs were not auto-incremented, this is trivial:

`def insert(cId: Int, cName: String, subcId: Int, subcName: String) = 
    DBIO.seq(
      categories +=(subcId, subcName, None),
      categories +=(cId, cName, Some(subcId))
    )`

But when ID ARE auto-incrememnted, this get's tricky. [As stated in the documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting), I need to use `returning` combined with projection to column that needs to be returned, like:

`val categoryId = 
   (categories returning categories.map(_.id)) += (0, name, None)`

Now I can use returned ID when inserting the second row. Awesome. But then how can I close sequences of DB actions, since I am returned with the ID, but not the action itself?

`def insert(cName: String, subcName: String): DBIOAction[Int, Stream, Write]  = ???`

Answer (score 2):

So I will answer my own question as somebody might find it weird at first as I did.

`val categoryId = 
   (categories returning categories.map(_.id)) += (0, name, None)`

Trick is that `categoryId` is also a **DBIOAction**, not an Int as I originally expected it to be. Trivial, but there you go.

Comment: sorry for the late comment, but what was the final version of the code? Did you need to break the DBIO.seq(...) in two calls?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do (I've done something similar in a project of mine):

```
def insert(cName: String, subcName: String) = {
  for {
    id <- (categories returning categories.map(_.id)) += (subcName, None)
    _ <- categories +=(cName, Some(id))
  } yield ()
```

and then I'd call the function like:

```
db.run(insert(categoryName, subCategoryName))
```